# How to find which job board provide web service to post job there

Tags: web-services

I am working on an application which need to post jobs on job board using their web services,but i don't know how to find that.Here i have a list of job boards can anyone suggest me which among them provide free web services ??? Here is my list

```
BetterJobs
DataFrenzy
Glassdoor
Jobs.com
Juju
OLX
oodle
Resume Library
TheLadders
Trovit
Yakas
```

So anyone have any information about the free webservices among them ??? PLease share with me

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for a public API to post jobs to these sites. At least in the case of TheLadders (where I work), we don't currently have one (But if a compelling case is made for building one, it could be something we'd consider.)